# Corona sdk: lua memory leak

Tags: ios, memory, lua, coronasdk, memory-leaks

I am currently making a simple app in CoronaSDK (Lua), but i have some problems:

- I wanted a score counter, but since I made it my app keeps crashing.
- I can't figure out how to make a "good" score counter.
  Some help would really be appreciated. :)

Code:

```
function points(num)
    tmr = timer.performWithDelay(1000, points, 0)
    num = 5
    score = 2
    score = score + num
    scoreTxt.text = "score: " .. score
    scoreTxt:setReferencePoint(display.TopLeftReferencePoint)
    scoreTxt.x = screenLeft + 15
end
```

Didn't really know were to put the `timer.cancel(tmr)`

```
function explode()
    timer.cancel(tmr)
    explosion.x = jet.x
    explosion.y = jet.y
    explosion.isVisible = true
    explosion:play()
    jet.isVisible = false   
    timer.performWithDelay(3000, gameOver, 1)
end

function onCollision(event)
    if event.phase == "began" then
        if jet.collided == false then
            timer.cancel(tmr)
            num = nil;
            score = nil;
            jet.collided = true 
            jet.bodyType = "static"

            explode()
        end
    end
end
```

Some more information don't know if you need it :P

```
score = 1.5;
num = 1;
scoreTxt = display.newText ("Score:", 0, 0, "Helvetica", 20)
scoreTxt:setReferencePoint(display.TopLeftReferencePoint)
scoreTxt.x = display.screenOriginX + 10
scoreTxt.y = display.screenOriginX + 5
screenLeft = display.screenOriginX
```

If someone could help me i would really appreciate it :)
Thanks in advance

Comment: I can not understand your problem.How output u expecting.and search over the net and learn some basic syntax to use timer in corona sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tmr = timer.performWithDelay(1000, points, 0)
```

This line in points function makes unlimited function calls. Thats the cause of leak. If you want to call points function at every second, you should call that from somewhere else.